# How to keep spans after modifying the string - android

Tags: java, android

When I use the function toString() and I edit the string such as replacing letters and adding other letters And I assign the text to SpannableStringBuilder(newString) It immediately deletes all the spans.. How to keep spans after modifying the string??

```
text = text.toString().replace("⠀-⠀⠀-⠀", "⠀-⠀");

spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);

binding.editText.setText(spannableStringBuilder);`
```

Comment: you can use SpannableStringBuilder with Spannable Flags to add or remove span. and toString not directly using with text, using with spannableStringBuilder string.

Comment: @MdEusufUddin what do you mean with using with spannableStringBuilder string? i wanna replace all "- -" to "-" and the function replace not exist in spannableStringBuilder

Answer (score 0):

(I'm sorry that my answer is in Kotlin but hopefully it can solve your issue)

The reason why your spans are deleted is likely because of the `.toString()` call. To copy your spanned string into a new `SpannableStringBuilder` so that you can modify it *while keeping the spans*, pass it to the `SpannableStringBuilder(CharSequence text)` constructor directly.

For replacement, `SpannableStringBuilder` has a `replace(int start, int end, CharSequence tb)` method, but it takes a range to determine what to replace and not a string, so you have to find the start and end indices of what you're trying to replace. You could write a function like this:

```
fun SpannableStringBuilder.replace(oldValue: String, newValue: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false) {

    // find first occurrence
    var occurrenceIndex: Int = indexOf(oldValue, 0, ignoreCase)
    if (occurrenceIndex < 0) return
    
    val searchStep = newValue.length.coerceAtLeast(1)
    
    do {
        val start = occurrenceIndex
        val end = occurrenceIndex + oldValue.length
        this.replace(start, end, newValue) // <- this is the replace from SpannableStringBuilder
        occurrenceIndex = indexOf(oldValue, occurrenceIndex + searchStep, ignoreCase)
    } while (occurrenceIndex > 0) // repeat until no occurrences left
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
val text: SpannedString = // ...

val copyAndReplace = SpannableStringBuilder(text).apply {
    replace("⠀-⠀⠀-⠀", "⠀-⠀")
}
```

I can't be entirely sure of course but I tested it and it seems to work fine